# How to achieve this opacity on scroll behavior?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a sticky header similar to [the one seen here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/).

It gradually changes the header's opacity from 0 to 1 based on how much you've scrolled. Currently you need to scroll up about 70px for it to reach full opacity. And scroll down 70px for it to go back to opacity 0.

What kind of logic do I need to gradually increase/decrease the opacity based on scroll?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a <strike>very ugly</strike> proof of concept (the important part is the javascript):

```js
var prevScrollY = 0;
var opacity = 1;
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
  if (scrollY > prevScrollY) {
    opacity -= (scrollY - prevScrollY) / 70;
  } else {
    opacity += (prevScrollY - scrollY) / 70;
  }
  opacity = Math.max(Math.min(opacity, 1), 0);
  header.style.opacity = opacity;
  prevScrollY = scrollY;
});
```

```css
#header {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <p>
    This is the header
  </p>
</div>
<br>
<p>
This is just filler
</p>
<p>
This is just filler
</p>
<p>
This is just filler
</p>
<p>
This is just filler
</p>
<p>
This is just filler
</p>
<p>
This is just filler
</p>
<p>
This is just filler
</p>
<p>
This is just filler
</p>
<p>
This is just filler
</p>
<p>
This is just filler
</p>
<p>
This is just filler
</p>
<p>
This is just filler
</p>
<p>
This is just filler
</p>
<p>
This is just filler
</p>
<p>
This is just filler
</p>
<p>
This is just filler
</p>
<p>
This is just filler
</p>
<p>
This is just filler
</p>
<p>
This is just filler
</p>
```

Comment: How would I expand this snippet so I can always see the header on scroll up, even when I'm not at the top of the page?

Comment: @sneakyvince I've edited my post to include the feature.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped alot.